# JS - Remove all <img> inside a div

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div that only contains images.

```
 <div class="content">
    <img src="img.png"/>
    <img src="img.png"/>
    <img src="img.png"/>
    <img src="img.png"/>
</div>
```

And I need to remove all `<img>` within the div.

With `jquery` , it can be done by

```
$('.content img').remove();
```

But how do I achieve this with only JavaScript?

Comment: Use a loop with `document.querySelectorAll(".content img")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select all `img` elements and then use [`remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove) to removes the images from the DOM.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".content img")
  .forEach(img => img.remove());
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <img src="img.png" />
  <img src="img.png" />
  <img src="img.png" />
  <img src="img.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for(var i=0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].parentNode.removeChild(images[i]);
}
```

Hope this will work for you